# PL/SQL: 3-dimensional associative array where last array can be varray of number or varchar2 (with variable length)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Basically I am creating a package that will replicate the procedures/functions of Oracle Form's RecordGroup functions. I am having a hard time simulating these functionalities. Specially where a RecordGroup (2nd dimension) could have either a number or varchar2(of any length) column (3rd dimension).

What I am thinking is for the package to have a 3-dimensional associative array in order to simulate the oracle forms procedures.

**1st Dimension** - Collection of all RecordGroups defined in the package session. This will be a table of RecordGroups indexed by varchar2.

**2nd Dimension** - This dimension will be the RecordGroup itself, a table of varrays that will simulate as the record group's columns. This table will be indexed by varchar2 denoting the column's name

**3rd Dimension** - This will be a varray of either number or varchar2 with length specific to a column. This varray will be indexed by its row number.

My question is if it is possible to have a table such as the defined RecordGroup such that it is a table of varrays of varying datatypes. If so, any ideas on how to do it? If not possible, is there anyway I could implement the behavior defined? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean *a given record group* contains either numeric rows or string rows, but not a mix of both.  In which case: create SQL types to hold the data and use polymorphism to create a generic record grtoup super type and specfic subtypes for the different data types.

```
create or replace type record_group_t as object (
     rg_name varchar2(30)
     , rg_type varchar2(6)  -- i.e. number or string
 ) 
not final not instantiable;
/

create or replace type rg_strings_nt as table of varchar2(128);
/

create or replace type rg_numbers_nt as table of number(38,0);
/

create or replace type record_group_string under record_group_t (
    rg_recs rg_strings_nt
)
final instantiable;
/

create or replace type record_group_number under record_group_t (
    rg_recs rg_numbers_nt
)
final instantiable;
/
```

You may wish to change specfic values, or even allow for more specialized sub-types.  Also, the `record_group_t.rg_type` attribute might not be necessary - it depends on how yopu're going to use these things.

Then your collection of record groups - the first dimension - becomes simply:

```
create or replace type record_group_nt as table of record_group_t;
/
```

Yiou can switch between the sub-types of `record_group_t` useing TREAT() and CAST().  Rewad the Object developer's guide to [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjbas.htm#sthref242).